# OTP with spring security

Tags: java, spring, security, authentication, one-time-password

How can I implement OTP 2 factors authentication in spring security. First, DB username and password authentication and based on user role redirect to OTP authentication?

Comment: This can help https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-two-factor-authentication-with-soft-token

Comment: Can anyone apport a tutorial to do it in the right way

Comment: @MarcosRandulfeGarrido

https://medium.com/javarevisited/spring-boot-two-factor-authentication-78e00aa10176

Answer (score 1):

You could look into using a plugin like this:

https://github.com/upcrob/spring-security-otp

It hasn't been updated in awhile, but at the very least may give you a good starting point.